# DataBinding append to TextBox

Tags: c#, forms, data-binding, textbox, append

I have added 'INotifyPropertyChanged' to a class. Now I want to track changes to a property in a form textbox (TxtLog) by **appending** the property value string. The form textbox (TxtLog) can also be written to by other classes that append strings.

On another field I use the following code (working):

```
Status.DataBindings.Add("Text", Fields.Track, "Status");
```

So code like this would be working:

```
TxtLog.DataBindings.Add("Text", Fields.Track, "Log");
```

But this would reset the textbox value. I want the databinding to add to the field 'TxtLog'.

Can this be achieved?

Comment: more detail is needed to know where the problem is;  please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The problem is that I want the databind to append it's value to the existing value in the textbox. This direct link overwrites the value.

Comment: did you read the MCVE article?  more detail / context / code is needed to see *why* `TxtLog.DataBindings.Add()` isn't behaving as expected;  also, post your additional detail as an edit to the *body* of your question; comments are not well-suited for providing much detail

Comment: Do you mean that every change in `Status` should appear in the `TxtLog`?

Comment: Yes by appending to the current value of TxtLog.Also TxtLog can be written to by other classes. A two way bind won't suit my need also.